# What does it mean that objc_msgSend() is passed "a pointer to the reciever's data"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, objective-c-runtime

In Apple's ObjC Runtime Guide, it describes what the `objc_msgSend()` function does for dynamic dispatch:

> 1. It first finds the procedure (method implementation) that the selector refers to. Since the same method can be implemented
>      differently by separate classes, the precise procedure that it finds
>      depends on the class of the receiver.
> 2. It then calls the procedure, passing it the **receiving object (a pointer to its data)**, along with any arguments that were specified
>      for the method.
> 3. Finally, it passes on the return value of the procedure as its own return value.

I was confused in the second step, where it mentioned **"receiving object (a pointer to its data)**

What is that?

Can somebody give me a illustration to clarify it?

Comment: The "receiving object" is the "self" of the method that you are calling. The method needs to know what "self" is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will explain it in detail:  http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/

In short, every Objective-C method is really a C function that has two *mandatory* arguments and then whatever arguments are passed to the method.

I.e. this:

<strike>`- (void) foo:sender;`</strike>

```
- (void) foo:(id)sender;
```

Is really this C function:

```
void foo(id self, SEL _cmd, id sender);
```

The *pointer to the data* refers to the `self` parameter.  Through that pointer to an object, the compiler generates all references to any instance variables of `self`.

Comment: Is that supposed to be `- (void)foo:(id)sender` or does it automatically use `id` when a type isn't specified?

Comment: @indragie Yup -- compiler defaults to `(id)`.  That is actually no longer recommended, but old habits die hard.  Fixed.